# How to connect with two or more users to hyper-v virtual machine at the same time?

Tags: windows-8, virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

The local computer is with Windows 8. I have hyper-v virtual machine with Windows Server 2016. I have created three additional users (users A, B and C) in the Windows Server 2016 machine. Now, I want to log in it, with user A and user B at the same time. Is this possible?

I can change anything (settings, security) on each machine. I guess I need to use the remote desktop connection, but cannot make it work with the virtual machine. I am currently log in using the Hyper-V connect interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but in order to accomplish that you have to do number of things, at minimum these 2:

1. Setup networking so it is bridged - this way your server 2016 will get it's own IP address (if you are using DHCP), note that IP address and RDP to that, instead of your laptop. Even better, setup a static IP on the server 2016 and create a DNS record
2. In order to have multiple users using the server setup Terminal
   Services and get the correct licensing